# how to handle string return with jquery post

Tags: jquery, webmethod

I'm calling a webservice that returns a string, but I cannot figure a way how to handle the return string. This is the code that I'm using now:

```
$('#soap-form').submit(function () {
            $.post($(this).attr('action'), { Source: "values here are", SiteGroup: $('#dropdown-select').val(), Identifier: $('#indentifier-input').val(), Password: $('#password-input').val() }, function (data) { if (data != null) alert(data); });
            return false;
        });
```

It returns just an empty string, but the method is setup to return error messages and success etc.. any ideas?

**EDIT**
firebug: 
response tab is empy, but when I don't use the jquery post the method returns a `<string>error</string>`

**EDIT**
Do I have to do anything for the method to return string? Like enter a return type or is it enough with string as type for the method?

Comment: What does Firebug say your post is returning?

Comment: response tab is empy, but when i dont use the jquery post the method returns a <string>error</string>

Comment: Page Method is expecting JSON data type.. see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418037/failed-jquery-call-of-page-method) question and its accepted answer for code sample.

Comment: i already tried to set json on my post as datatype but then nothing happends. this is a soap method webservice im calling that returns a string, check my edit

Comment: If the response tab is empty, then there's something wrong with your request.  Check the POST variables, the URL, and the headers.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#soap-form').submit(function () {
            $.post(
                    $(this).attr('action'), 
                    { Source: "values here are", SiteGroup: $('#dropdown-select').val(), Identifier: $('#indentifier-input').val(), Password: $('#password-input').val() }, 
                    function (data) { 
                          if (data != null) alert(data); 
                    }
             );
            return false;
 });
```

this is better

to catch an error, you can use `.error();`

```
$('#soap-form').submit(function () {
            $.post(
                    $(this).attr('action'), 
                    { Source: "values here are", SiteGroup: $('#dropdown-select').val(), Identifier: $('#indentifier-input').val(), Password: $('#password-input').val() }, 
                    function (data) { 
                          if (data != null) alert(data); 
                    }
             ).error(function(){
                 // do whatever you want with this error
             });
            return false;
 });
```

[demo](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/88c9b)

Comment: This goes on to a empty page on the soap method address so its like the return false does not matter.